# HICococaView not compiling with GCC 4.2

Tags: cocoa, xcode, gcc, macos-carbon

We have a large Carbon based (PowerPlant) application that we are looking finally to port over to Cocoa. We will be doing this incrementally and a first step is to try to get a Cocoa view into a Carbon window.

The problem seems to be that when I use any of the functions from HICocoaView.h the application will not compile unless I switch the compiler from GCC 4.2 to GCC 4.0.

Using any compiler other than GCC 4.0 I get an error in XCode that the functions are unavailable e.g. "HICocoaViewCreate is unavailable".

I can't figure out why this won't work, will we have to switch to the older compiler or is there some setting we can change to get it to compile?

Any help or pointers to useful documentation on porting Carbon to Cocoa greatly appreciated. I've read through the old Carbon Cocoa Integration guide but it doesn't mention this.

**Edit:** As requested here's the output from the build for the gcc command line:-

> /Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -x objective-c++ **-arch i386**
>   -fmessage-length=0 -pipe -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -fasm-blocks -O0 -Wmissing-prototypes -Wreturn-type -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -D__IMPRO_DEBUG_BUILD__ -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk -mfix-and-continue
>   -mmacosx-version-min=10.5 -gdwarf-2 "-I/Users/matt/Code/MattsFeatureBranch/Modules/User
>   Notes/Mac/../../../(Intermediates)/Debug/User Notes.build/Debug/Module
>   Bundle.build/User Notes.hmap" -Wparentheses -Wno-conversion
>   -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-multichar -Wno-deprecated-declarations "-F/Users/matt/Code/MattsFeatureBranch/Modules/User
>   Notes/Mac/../../../Build Products/Mac/Debug/Plugins" "-F../../../Build
>   Products/Mac/Debug" "-F../../../Third Party/Mac/NVidia"
>   "-I/Users/matt/Code/MattsFeatureBranch/Modules/User
>   Notes/Mac/../../../Build Products/Mac/Debug/Plugins/include"
>   -I../X-Platform -I../../../Common/Mac -I../../../Common/X-Platform -I../../../DLLs/ArcadiaCore/Mac -I../../../DLLs/ArcadiaCore/X-Platform "-I../../../Third Party/Mac/Powerplant"
>   -I/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk/Developer/Headers/FlatCarbon "-I../../../Third Party/X-Platform/boost_1_38_0"
>   -I../../../DLLs/ArcadiaImaging/Mac -I../../../DLLs/ArcadiaImaging/X-Platform -I../../../DLLs/ArcadiaDatabase/Mac -I../../../DLLs/ArcadiaDatabase/X-Platform -I../../../DLLs/ArcadiaUI/Mac -I../../../DLLs/ArcadiaUI/X-Platform "-I../../../Third Party/Mac/Powerplant Extras"
>   -I../../../DLLs/ArcadiaDevices/Mac -I../../../DLLs/ArcadiaDevices/X-Platform -I../../../DLLs/Arcadia3D/Mac -I../../../DLLs/Arcadia3D/X-Platform "-I/Users/matt/Code/MattsFeatureBranch/Modules/User
>   Notes/Mac/../../../(Intermediates)/Debug/User Notes.build/Debug/Module
>   Bundle.build/DerivedSources/i386"
>   "-I/Users/matt/Code/MattsFeatureBranch/Modules/User
>   Notes/Mac/../../../(Intermediates)/Debug/User Notes.build/Debug/Module
>   Bundle.build/DerivedSources" -fpermissive -fasm-blocks -include
>   "/Users/matt/Code/MattsFeatureBranch/Modules/User
>   Notes/Mac/../../../(Intermediates)/Debug/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/XPrefix-acshmfbgvfwrdqbyayvgnckkypgr/XPrefix.h"
>   -c "/Users/matt/Code/MattsFeatureBranch/Modules/User Notes/Mac/MUserNotesView.cpp" -o
>   "/Users/matt/Code/MattsFeatureBranch/Modules/User
>   Notes/Mac/../../../(Intermediates)/Debug/User Notes.build/Debug/Module
>   Bundle.build/Objects-normal/i386/MUserNotesView.o"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From HICocoaView.h in both the 10.5 and the 10.6 SDK:

```
#if !__LP64__
extern OSStatus
HICocoaViewCreate(
  NSView *     inNSView,        /* can be NULL */
  OptionBits   inOptions,
  HIViewRef *  outHIView)                                                       AVAILABLE_MAC_OS_X_VERSION_10_5_AND_LATER;
…
#endif  /* !__LP64__ */
```

This means that `HICocoaViewCreate()` is not available on 64-bit (`LP64`) targets, i.e., if you need to use this function you have to target i386 (or PowerPC).

GCC 4.0 targets i386 by default even when run on 64-bit capable machines. On the other hand, GCC 4.2 targets x86_64 by default on 64-bit machines:

```
$ gcc-4.0 a.c; lipo -info a.out
Non-fat file: a.out is architecture: i386

$ gcc-4.2 a.c; lipo -info a.out
Non-fat file: a.out is architecture: x86_64
```

If you want to use both `HICocoaViewCreate()` and GCC 4.2, tell it to create (and use) 32-bit objects/binaries by passing `-arch i386`. For instance,

```
$ gcc-4.2 a.c -arch i386; lipo -info a.out
Non-fat file: a.out is architecture: i386
```

---

Even though part of Carbon is available for 64-bit targets, you’ll notice in the [64-bit Guide for Carbon Developers](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/Carbon64BitGuide/HIToolboxChanges/HIToolboxChanges.html) that much of HIToolbox simply isn’t available.

As for migrating from Carbon to Cocoa, it’s a whole new Objective-C API for the most part. I’m not aware of any simple migration guide, and [Peter Hosey’s answer to a similar question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1366168/strategies-for-porting-carbon-code-to-cocoa/1366541#1366541) is worth reading.

Comment: +1 for the excellent answer and reason behind the problem.  Well said!

Comment: Thanks for the help. That really is a great answer, just what I needed to know.

Comment: After looking at this a bit more in the XCode build config it seems we are compiling only to 32bit architectures already. Unless I'm missing something, there must be something else.

Comment: @Matt Have you checked the build results window to see what is the actual GCC invocation when Xcode builds the project? It’d help if you posted the command-line in your original question.

Comment: @Bavarious I've added the output from the build window that show the GCC invocation. The architecture is set to i386. Not convinced we're not doing something else wrong though. Thanks.

Comment: @Matt There’s something else going on, then. I’ve just created a project targeting Mac OS 10.5/i386, linked Carbon, used `HICocoaViewCreate()`, and the project built just fine. What is the error message you get when building your project?

Comment: @Bavarious The error message isn't that useful, I'm getting error: 'HICocoaViewCreate' is unavailable (declared at /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Frameworks/HIToolbox.framework/Headers/HICocoaView.h:116)

Comment: @Bavarious Think I may have found the problem. Using Xcode's preprocess on the file, the availability macros are expanding to "unavailable". Someone has defined MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED in a precompiled header as 10.4, looks like this is overriding the project settings. No idea why it doesn't effect the GCC 4.0 compiler though. I'm rebuilding the whole project, but it seems to have fixed it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Matt I’m sorry but I cannot reproduce your build error. As far as I can tell my GCC command line invocation matches yours and it builds without errors here. If you’ve changed your project settings, maybe something needs recompiling (precompiled prefix?). Try cleaning your build and then rebuild your project. I’m sorry I can’t offer more specific help.

Comment: @Matt Ah, it was a problem with the precompiled prefix, then. Glad you’ve found that.

Comment: @Matt, if you're building multiple architectures at once, you might be getting confused by the fact that you are building both i386 (and that's what you copied) and some 64-bit architecture, and the error is coming from the build for the 64-bit architecture. Be very careful in the Xcode build results window—it's very easy to look at a build step that actually succeeded when you mean to examine one that failed.